# Using LocalStorage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a side navigation bar:

```
<li class="side-nav-tab">
  <a href="/item"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Items<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="side-nav-tab">
  <a href="/client"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Clients<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="side-nav-tab">
  <a href="/quote"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Quotes<span></span></a>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.side-nav-tab').on('click', function(){
          var arrow = $(this).find('span').attr('class');

          if ((arrow == undefined) || (arrow == '')) {
            $('.side-nav-tab').find('span').not(this).removeClass('fa arrow');
            $(this).find('span').addClass('fa arrow');
          }

        })
    })
```

The code above works (adds the class 'fa arrow' to the span) but it's only temporary. The problem is that when you click $('.side-nav-tab'), it directs you to that route, does a page reload, and I lose the 'fa arrow' class I just added.

After doing some research, it appears I could use localStorage, but have been unsuccessful in trying:

```
var storage = localStore.getItem(arrow)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: please provide us with a fiddle with some working CSS as well . thanks

Comment: what error have in console

Comment: there's no console error because it is functional, it just reloads and the class gets removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use localstorage for this. The proper, and simpler, way is to use `preventDefault()` to prevent the link from firing. Try this event handler:

```
$('.side-nav-tab').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var arrow = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
  if ((arrow == undefined) || (arrow == '')) {
        $('.side-nav-tab').find('span').not(this).removeClass('fa arrow');
        $(this).find('span').addClass('fa arrow');
   }
 });
```

Comment: thanks Dave! this ended up working well. appreciate the help!